# convert from 'Platform::String ^' to 'const char *' when adding a const char *

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cli, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am porting a code (using C++ VS2015 in Windows 10) to a Universal Windows Application (UWP). It uses a macro (#define) that concatenates various const strings at compile time and sends a "const char *" as parameter to a function (not pointing to the first element). A simple example is as follows:

```
const char * s = ((const char *)("xxxx1234" "567" "89") + 4);
printf("[%s]", s );
```

in a common C++ program, it prints

```
[123456789] // <-- OK
```

The same, but for "Universal Windows", yields the error:

```
 error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Platform::String ^' to 'const char *'
```

If I omit the "+ 4" it works fine but I dont get the correct pointer offset. Prints

```
[xxxx123456789] <---- NG
```

How can I convert types or avoid defining the strings as Platform::String ? Preferably in one line, since it is a (#define) macro

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it. Changed it to

```
const char * s = (const_cast<char *>("xxxx1234" "567" "89") + 4);
```